# How to Sanitise the logged data when using log4j2?

Tags: filter, log4j2, interceptor, esapi

I need to validate the logs currently being written using log4j2 for sanitizing the input passed to it. I see ESAPI API provides an option to sanitize the input passed to it.

My question is I am not sure how I can use the ESAPI with logging methods.

Is there something like a filter or interceptor which I need to add for while logging in my methods to transparently filter and sanitise the logged text accordingly or should I write a custom Logger Class which extends the base Logger class and then logs accordingly by wrapping the call to ESAPI api.

If anyone has faced a similar issue can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

I’m guessing that with “sanitise” you mean things like obfuscating password strings and perhaps replacing IDs with tokens.

Log4j2 provides a [Rewrite](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RewriteAppender) appender that allows you to replace a LogEvent with another LogEvent before it’s passed to the destination (e.g. File) Appender.

Alternatively you can use Log4j2 [Filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html) to prevent some log events from going to certain (or all) appenders. This may be too drastic for your needs.